# New command with alias counter

Tags: macros, arguments

I'm trying to make a command which will create a new theorem environment and link the counter for it to a specified other counter. For example, I'd like to be able to do something where my theorem, proposition, definition, etc. environments all have the same counters. I've tried the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{aliascnt} 

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\DeclareTheorem}{ m m m !o }{%
\theoremstyle{#1}%
\IfNoValueTF{#4} {%
    \newtheorem{#2}{#3}% 
}{% 
    \newaliascnt{#2}{#4}%
    \newtheorem{#2}[#2]{#3}%
}%
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. It doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't compile or something. If I require five arguments, as below, then it works.

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\DeclareTheorem}{ m m m m !o }{%
\theoremstyle{#1}%
\IfNoValueTF{#5} {%
    \newtheorem{#2}{#3}% 
}{% 
    \newaliascnt{#4}{#5}%
    \newtheorem{#2}[#4]{#3}%
}%
}
```

However, I'd prefer to automatically have the alias counter to have the same name as the theorem environment, so that I don't have to put in five different options every time. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual of the aliascnt-package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/aliascnt.pdf) says:

> 1.2 Syntax
>
> Macro names in user land contain the package name `aliascnt` in order to
> prevent name clashes.
>
> `\newaliascnt{⟨ALIASCNT⟩}{⟨BASECNT⟩}`
>
> An alias counter *⟨ALIASCNT⟩* is created that does
> not allocate a new TeX counter register. It shares the count register
> and the clear list with counter *⟨BASECNT⟩*. If the
> value of either the two registers is changed, the changes affects
> both.
>
> `\aliascntresetthe{⟨ALIASCNT⟩}`
>
> This fixes a problem with `\newtheorem` if it is fooled by an alias
> counter with the same name:
>
> ```
> \newtheorem{foo}{Foo}% counter "foo"
> \newaliascnt{bar}{foo}% alias counter "bar"
> \newtheorem{bar}[bar]{Bar}
> \aliascntresetthe{bar}
> ```

I suppose you need `\aliascntresetthe`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{aliascnt} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\DeclareTheorem}{ m m m !o }{%
  % #1 = theoremstyle
  % #2 = name of theorem-emvironment
  % #3 = Phrase introducing the theorem.
  % #4 = the counter to use instead of allocating a new counter
  \theoremstyle{#1}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#4}{%
    \newtheorem{#2}{#3}% 
  }{% 
    % In case the counter to use is not defined define it:
    \@ifundefined{c@#4}{\newcounter{#4}}{}%
    \newaliascnt{#2}{#4}%
    \newtheorem{#2}[#2]{#3}%
    \aliascntresetthe{#2}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\DeclareTheorem{plain}{ThmA}{A-theorem}
\newcommand\ThmAname{A-theorem}
\DeclareTheorem{plain}{ThmB}{B-theorem}[ThmA]
\newcommand\ThmBname{B-theorem}
\DeclareTheorem{plain}{ThmC}{C-theorem}[ThmA]
\newcommand\ThmCname{C-theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThmA}
\label{ThmA1}This is an \ThmAname.
\end{ThmA}

\begin{ThmB}
\label{ThmB2}This is a \ThmBname.
\end{ThmB}

\begin{ThmC}
\label{ThmC3}This is a \ThmCname.
\end{ThmC}

Referencing:

\verb|\autoref{ThmA1}| yields: \autoref{ThmA1}

\verb|\autoref{ThmB2}| yields: \autoref{ThmB2}

\verb|\autoref{ThmC3}| yields: \autoref{ThmC3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Actually, reading your comment, I realized that I could in fact use ```c@#2``` in the place where I was confused, and that would fix it all!

Comment: @boink Be aware that a LaTeX-counter is more than just a `\count`-register. `\newcounter` also defines "infrastructure" like  `\p@<counter>` , `\the<counter>`, `\cl@<counter>` and in case hyperref is loaded you also need to take care of things like `\theH<ccounter>` and `\<counter>autorefname`/`\<counter>name`. Some of these things are done by the aliascnt-package. More details about LaTeX's counter-infrastructure can be found in the commented [LaTeX 2e sources, file m:ltcounts.dtx , 22.1 Environment Counter Macros](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf#subsection.22.1).